# String extraction with regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract bunch of information from filenames using regular expressions in R. As I am matching the pattern, str_view() is showing me the correct set of strings. Yet, when I am trying to sub those and extract the remaining portion, it doesn't work. I also tried str_extract() but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
fname <- "TC2L6C_2020-08-14_1516_6C-ASG_29_00020.tab"

fext <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(fname)

stringr::str_view(fext, ".*-ASG_\\d+_", match = TRUE)

P_num <- gsub(".*-ASG_\\d{2}_", "", fext)

P_num <- stringr::str_extract(fname, "(?<=-ASG_\\d+)([^_])*(?=\\.tab)")
```

Comment: `fname` is your input string. What is your expected output ?

Comment: My expected output is the last five digits. The question is somewhat misleading. As I just tested with the individual file name, the gsub() seems to work. However, I am getting the filenames through list.files(). That's when, its returning me NA for the output.

Comment: That's what I was confused about. `gsub` seems to return the expected output for the example shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `trimws` from `base R`

```
 trimws(fname, whitespace = ".*_|\\..*")
[1] "00020"
```

#### data

```
fname <- "TC2L6C_2020-08-14_1516_6C-ASG_29_00020.tab"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach using `sub`:

```r
fname <- "TC2L6C_2020-08-14_1516_6C-ASG_29_00020.tab"
output <- sub("^.*-ASG_\\d+_(.*)\\.tab$", "\\1", fname)
output

[1] "00020"
```

Above we use a capture group to isolate the portion of the filename, sans extension, which you want to match.